# How to pass const_iterator and non const iterator in a single template call

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to know how to pass a const_iterator to a template. For example in the below call and function template.

The iterator for first1 and last 1 is

```
std::vector<std::pair<cv::Point_<float>, cv::Point_<float> > >::iterator
```

and the iterator for first2 and last2 is const_iterator

```
std::vector<std::pair<cv::Point_<float>, cv::Point_<float> > >::const_iterator

template < typename T>
T my_function(T __first1, T __last1, T __first2, T __last2, T __result)
{

}
```

Call is

```
my_function(co1.begin(), co1.end(), co2.begin(), co2,end(), result.begin());
```

Is there a way to pass both a normal iterator and a const_iterator in a single template?

The error is

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘my_function(std::vector<std::pair<cv::Point_<float>, cv::Point_<float> > >::iterator, std::vector<std::pair<cv::Point_<float>, cv::Point_<float> > >::iterator, std::vector<std::pair<cv::Point_<float>, cv::Point_<float> > >::const_iterator, std::vector<std::pair<cv::Point_<float>, cv::Point_<float> > >::const_iterator, std::vector<std::pair<cv::Point_<float>, cv::Point_<float> > >::iterator)’’
             my_function(co1.begin(), co1.end(), co2.begin(), co2.end(), result.begin());
```

Comment: I got it.. I just need to divide the template in T1 and T2..and it works !
template < typename T1, typename T2> T1 my_function(T1 __first1, T1 __last1, T2 __first2, T2 __last2, T1 __result)

Comment: what is `my_function`? can you modify it?

Comment: @user463035818 . found the answer myself.. should I delete this post?

Comment: dont delete it when there are already answers given. Consider to accept one of them or if you like you should even post your own answer (more answers is always good)

Comment: Just a unrelated comment for your interest: [Identifiers starting with two underscores are reserved for compiler vendors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1332041).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, you need different types so that deduction succeeds, not just `T`:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 my_function(T1 __first1, T1 __last1, T2 __first2, T2 __last2, T1 __result) { ... }
```

You can add a [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) check (advanced!) (whichever way you want):

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T2, T1>> // C++17 way
```

to preserve the restriction that `T2` is only a *const* version of `T1`. You might want to add a separate type for `_result` and the return type as well.

Comment: Most probably `result` also should have own type (`T3`).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to convert one iterator type to another just add another template type that will allow the two ranges to have two different types of iterators.

```
template < typename T, typename U, typename O>
T my_function(T __first1, T __last1, U __first2, U __last2, O __result)
{

}
```

<sup>added a third type for the output type as well</sup>

This makes the function much more generic and flexible.